# How do you mass create channels on Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

Hello I am making a bot that will basically make a whole discord server and I just can't figure out how to mass create channels so could someone tell me, please

Comment: You should show us what you have tried already. Post the code that creates the server and where it should mass create the channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Channels = ["Example Channel", "Example Channel 2"]; // Example of channel names.
const Guild = await client.guilds.create("My Guild"); // Creating the guild.

Channels.forEach(channelName => { // Looping through Channels array to get the channels names.
    Guild.channels.create(channelName); // Creating the channels.
});

const GuildChannel = Guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === "text").find(x => x.position == 0); // Getting the first channel in the guild.
const Invite = await GuildChannel.createInvite({maxAge: 0, maxUses: 1}); // Creating and invite.
message.channel.send(`I created the guild ${Guild.name}. Invite Link: ${Invite.url}`); // Sending the invite link to the current channel.

// Warning: client.guilds.create() is only available to bots in fewer than 10 guilds.guilds!
```

Comment: Which version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is your node version since the latest Discord.js version is 12.2.0. Also, I think something else from your code is causing the error.